# Unable to open the .jmx file on Jmeter

Tags: apache, jmeter

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L2ybH.png)I have recorded the script in jmeter and executed it successfully but when I tried to open the same file again to do some changes then it threw an error like this:

[jmeterError1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L2ybH.png)

2023-08-15 13:33:53,316 INFO o.j.r.JARSourceHTTP: Found cached repo
2023-08-15 13:33:53,452 INFO o.j.r.PluginManager: Plugins Status: [jpgc-casutg=2.10, jpgc-ffw=2.0, jpgc-plugins-manager=1.10, jmeter-core=5.5, jmeter-ftp=5.5, jmeter-http=5.5, jmeter-jdbc=5.5, jmeter-jms=5.5, jmeter-junit=5.5, jmeter-java=5.5, jmeter-ldap=5.5, jmeter-mail=5.5, jmeter-mongodb=5.5, jmeter-native=5.5, jmeter-tcp=5.5, jmeter-components=5.5]
2023-08-15 14:12:57,126 INFO o.a.j.s.FileServer: Default base='E:\apache-jmeter-5.5\bin'
2023-08-15 14:13:05,539 INFO o.a.j.g.a.Load: Loading file: E:\apache-jmeter-5.5\bin\loginupdate.jmx
2023-08-15 14:13:05,539 INFO o.a.j.s.FileServer: Set new base='E:\apache-jmeter-5.5\bin'
2023-08-15 14:13:05,647 INFO o.a.j.s.SaveService: Testplan (JMX) version: 2.2. Testlog (JTL) version: 2.2
2023-08-15 14:13:05,653 INFO o.a.j.s.SaveService: Using SaveService properties version 5.0
2023-08-15 14:13:05,655 INFO o.a.j.s.SaveService: Using SaveService properties file encoding UTF-8
2023-08-15 14:13:05,656 INFO o.a.j.s.SaveService: Loading file: E:\apache-jmeter-5.5\bin\loginupdate.jmx
2023-08-15 14:13:05,660 WARN o.j.r.p.TestPlanAnalyzer: Cannot parse file: E:\apache-jmeter-5.5\bin\loginupdate.jmx
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: Content is not allowed in prolog.
at org.apache.xerces.parsers.DOMParser.parse(Unknown Source) ~[xercesImpl-2.12.2.jar:?]
at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(Unknown Source) ~[xercesImpl-2.12.2.jar:?]
at javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder.parse(DocumentBuilder.java:122) ~[?:?]
at org.jmeterplugins.repository.plugins.TestPlanAnalyzer.getNodeListWithClassNames(TestPlanAnalyzer.java:130) ~[jmeter-plugins-manager-1.10.jar:?]
at org.jmeterplugins.repository.plugins.TestPlanAnalyzer.analyze(TestPlanAnalyzer.java:37) ~[jmeter-plugins-manager-1.10.jar:?]
at org.jmeterplugins.repository.plugins.PluginSuggester.analyzeTestPlan(PluginSuggester.java:51) ~[jmeter-plugins-manager-1.10.jar:?]
at org.jmeterplugins.repository.plugins.PluginSuggester.findPluginsToInstall(PluginSuggester.java:44) ~[jmeter-plugins-manager-1.10.jar:?]
at org.jmeterplugins.repository.plugins.PluginSuggester.checkAndSuggest(PluginSuggester.java:28) ~[jmeter-plugins-manager-1.10.jar:?]
at org.jmeterplugins.repository.logging.LoggerAppender.append(LoggerAppender.java:33) ~[jmeter-plugins-manager-1.10.jar:?]
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AppenderControl.tryCallAppender(AppenderControl.java:161) ~[log4j-core-2.17.2.jar:2.17.2]
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AppenderControl.callAppender0(AppenderControl.java:134) ~[log4j-core-2.17.2.jar:2.17.2]
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AppenderControl.callAppenderPreventRecursion(AppenderControl.java:125) ~[log4j-core-2.17.2.jar:2.17.2]
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AppenderControl.callAppender(AppenderControl.java:89) ~[log4j-core-2.17.2.jar:2.17.2]
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.LoggerConfig.callAppenders(LoggerConfig.java:675) ~[log4j-core-2.17.2.jar:2.17.2]
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.LoggerConfig.processLogEvent(LoggerConfig.java:633) ~[log4j-core-2.17.2.jar:2.17.2]
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.LoggerConfig.log(LoggerConfig.java:616) ~[log4j-core-2.17.2.jar:2.17.2]
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.LoggerConfig.log(LoggerConfig.java:552) ~[log4j-core-2.17.2.jar:2.17.2]
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AwaitCompletionReliabilityStrategy.log(AwaitCompletionReliabilityStrategy.java:82) ~[log4j-core-2.17.2.jar:2.17.2]
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.Logger.log(Logger.java:161) ~[log4j-core-2.17.2.jar:2.17.2]
at org.apache.logging.log4j.spi.AbstractLogger.tryLogMessage(AbstractLogger.java:2205) ~[log4j-api-2.17.2.jar:2.17.2]
at org.apache.logging.log4j.spi.AbstractLogger.logMessageTrackRecursion(AbstractLogger.java:2159) ~[log4j-api-2.17.2.jar:2.17.2]
at org.apache.logging.log4j.spi.AbstractLogger.logMessageSafely(AbstractLogger.java:2142) ~[log4j-api-2.17.2.jar:2.17.2]
at org.apache.logging.log4j.spi.AbstractLogger.logMessage(AbstractLogger.java:2034) ~[log4j-api-2.17.2.jar:2.17.2]
at org.apache.logging.log4j.spi.AbstractLogger.logIfEnabled(AbstractLogger.java:1899) ~[log4j-api-2.17.2.jar:2.17.2]
at org.apache.logging.slf4j.Log4jLogger.info(Log4jLogger.java:184) ~[log4j-slf4j-impl-2.17.2.jar:2.17.2]
at org.apache.jmeter.save.SaveService.loadTree(SaveService.java:425) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.5]
at org.apache.jmeter.gui.action.Load.loadProjectFile(Load.java:129) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.5]
at org.apache.jmeter.gui.action.Load.loadProjectFile(Load.java:101) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.5]
at org.apache.jmeter.gui.action.Load.doActionAfterCheck(Load.java:88) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.5]
at org.apache.jmeter.gui.action.AbstractActionWithNoRunningTest.doAction(AbstractActionWithNoRunningTest.java:44) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.5]
at org.apache.jmeter.gui.action.ActionRouter.performAction(ActionRouter.java:87) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.5]
at org.apache.jmeter.gui.action.ActionRouter.lambda$actionPerformed$0(ActionRouter.java:69) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.5]
at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:318) ~[?:?]
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:771) ~[?:?]
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:722) ~[?:?]
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:716) ~[?:?]
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:399) ~[?:?]
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86) ~[?:?]
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:741) ~[?:?]
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:203) ~[?:?]
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:124) ~[?:?]
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:113) ~[?:?]
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:109) ~[?:?]
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101) ~[?:?]
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:90) ~[?:?]
2023-08-15 14:13:05,673 WARN o.a.j.g.a.Load: Error in XML format. org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: only whitespace content allowed before start tag and not # (position: START_DOCUMENT seen #... @1:2)
2023-08-15 14:13:05,673 ERROR o.a.j.u.JMeterUtils: only whitespace content allowed before start tag and not # (position: START_DOCUMENT seen #... @1:2)

I have tried to debug it but couldn't get any solution. I have tried to update the JAVA as well but in vain. and also tried to check the jmeter.log and edit the jmx file in Notepad++ but no use.

Answer (score 0):

JMeter [.jmx test scripts](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/JMETER/JmxTestPlan) are basically [XML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML) files.

The error means that the file cannot be parsed, to wit it's not a [valid XML](https://codebeautify.org/xmlvalidator).

Try opening it with your favourite text/XML editor or [IDE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrated_development_environment), it might be the case it's corrupt somehow, i.e. there is a symbol in the beginning which makes the XML invalid.

If you want us to take a look at the script add it to your question somehow.

In case if the .xml file cannot be restored you will need to re-create it either manually or record using [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.html) or [JMeter Chrome Extension](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/13354690351377-The-BlazeMeter-Chrome-Extension-Record-JMeter-Selenium-or-Synchronized-JMeter-and-Selenium)